# Rails3 and Omniauth-google

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, omniauth

I've just got into using Omniauth for logging in with Twitter and Facebook and that's all working great. Then I started to work with Omniauth-google and couldn't find out where I signup to get my CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET.

Where do I sign up for OAuth 1.0 access through google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is pretty good at finding stuff about, well, Google. Here's what you're looking for:

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html

Comment: I read that and wasn't sure if I had to register or not. All done now. I had to register, upload a file, verify and then I got the key and secret.